# App crashes at getInputStream

Tags: android, crash, connection

Not sure how to handle this. The app crashes at getInputStream() call. The log messages appear until

```
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        try {

            URL url = new URL(params[0]);   
            Log.d(params[0],"URL"); 

            Authenticator.setDefault (new Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication ("username", "password".toCharArray());
                }
            });
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            Log.d("Afer conn", "Connection");   

            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            Log.d("Afer conn", "Step1");
            conn.setConnectTimeout(5000);
            Log.d("Afer conn", "Step2");

            //conn.connect();
            return conn.getInputStream().toString();

         } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
              Log.d(e.getMessage(), "Error1");
              return e.getMessage();
          } catch (ProtocolException e) {
              Log.d(e.getMessage(), "Error2");
              return e.getMessage();
          } catch (IOException e) { //It comes here
          Log.d(e.getMessage(), conn.getErrorStream().toString());
              conn.getErrorStream().toString();
              return e.getMessage();
          } catch ( Exception e ) {
              Log.d(e.getMessage(), "Error4");
              return e.getMessage();
          }
```

The message that appears at IOException block is this:
`Received authentication challenge is null`.

But the Username and Password are correct.

Comment: Check the response code.

Comment: It was there before. But it doesn't help. It crashes at getResponseCode line :(

Comment: Did you check whether your param[0] works in browser?

Comment: yes, it does. Checked it already.

Comment: If this is an Android app, should you be using the Apache HTTP Client instead of a URLConnection?